# Are the references to "the rapture" in Matthew 24 and Luke 17 gender specific?

Tags: soteriology, gender, rapture

I am intrigued  as to whether  the "two" (people)  referred to in relation to the "rapture" in Matthew 24 and Luke 17,  should be gender specific? With my limited knowledge of Greek, it appears that  the Greek word for two (δύο) has or may have a gender,  determined by the context.

In Matthew 24:40,  we read that two will be in a field with one (εἷς   male form) being taken and one  (εἷς  male) left behind.  And then in verse 41, that two will be grinding in a mill with one (μία  female)  taken and one (μία female )  left behind.  Then  In Luke 17:34, we read that  two will be (lying) upon a bed and one (εἷς  male) taken and the other (ἕτερος male) left behind. And then in verse 35 that two will be grinding with one (μία female) taken and the other (ἑτέρα female being left behind.

In each case,  "the one" and  "the other" appear to be gender specific.  So the correct rendition would be that  in Matthew, there are two men in a field and two women grinding and that in Luke, there are  two men (lying) upon a bed  and again, two women  grinding.   The pattern then is two men in one location followed by two women in another location.

The intrigue arises as to the manner in which the translations handle  these passages.  Nearly all freely refer to women in both gospels,  but the two men on a bed in particular, seems to be problematical.  Virtually all modern translations then become gender neutral. The NIV has two women grinding for Luke 17:35 but then two people on a bed for Luke 17:34.  The NASB changed its mind from 1977 to 1995 going from men to people.  Yet the women remain unchanged.  The KJB is consistent with men and women being bracketed in the respective verses. But then in Matthew 24:40, they  have two in a field.  The NKJV seems to be one of  very few translations that is consistent throughout and is presumably accurate in bracketing the gender in all four cases.

Am I missing something?  Are "modern" translations trying to be "politically correct"? If so, they could at least be consistent.

Comment: Where do you find the word "rapture" in the biblical text?

Comment: The word "rapture" does not appear in the text!  Verbs in Greek do not have gender.  Only nouns and adjectives have gender.  Is your question about the intended gender of the word "two"?

Comment: @user33515  The same place that we find the word "Trinity" I expect. How else are we to refer to the sudden disappearance of people all over the world?  I don't think it has (ever) happened yet.

Comment: @Dottard  As a new comer to Greek, my question is intended to check whether I have correctly interpreted the gender of the numbers "two" and "one" or and  "other" correctly?  There is a second question implied, which expresses my concern about the apparent inaccuracy of reputable translations on this point.  Could there be some reasonable/logical explanation?

Comment: @VinceDuffin - see my answer below.  The word "rapture" is no present but the number "one" and "the" does have gender as explained below.  The number two is very vague.

Answer (score 2):

The gender situation in these texts of Matt 24:40, 41 and Luke 17:34, 35 is more complicated that it appears.  Let me quote the texts and insert the gender of each noun, pronoun and adjective as either M, F, N, etc.

**Matt 24:40, 41**

> Then two [M, F, N] will be in the field: one [M] is taken, and one [M]
> is left.  Two [M, F, N] will be grinding at the mill: one [F] is
> taken, and one [F] is left.

**Luke 17:34, 35**

> I say to you, in that night there will be two [M, F, N] upon one bed:
> The [M] one [M] will be taken, and the [M] other [M] will be left.
> There will be two grinding at the same [place]: The [F] one [F] will
> be taken, and the [F] other [F] will be left."

Several things stand out in this analysis:

- Luke (typically) records more words than the briefer Matthew
- Nothing can be deduced from the word "two" as the same spelling is used for both masculine, feminine and neuter
- The word, "women" and "men" do not occur in the text
- The only way to infer the gender of the persons is from the gender of the nouns - an unreliable guide as masculine nouns are occasionally used for feminine people.  However, it is more likely that in this case, because of the different genders used in each case, different sexes are probably implied.

Thus we may infer the following:

- Two **[men]** in one bed
- Two **[women]** grinding at one mill

However, I would not lay too much stress on this conclusion as it almost beside the point - the main point is Jesus' teaching that it is impossible for humans to tell who will "be taken", ie, who goes to heaven or otherwise.

Lastly, The masculine gender is used in two senses - when referring to men specifically and sometimes when referring to both men and women.  It is this latter case that makes the translation of the masculine case, translating "people" grammatically permissible.  For example, in James 4:11, James addrses a comment to the "adelphoi" = literally "brethren" but many modern translations write, "brothers and sisters".  That is, "men do not own their own grammatical gender - it can cover both sexes.  See also 2 Thess 3:6 and many other places in the NT.

Comment: I think the real question is about modern translations.  Even though the other two verses explicitly say "two women" and "two men", for the one involving a bed they say "two people" or simply "two", even though the original is clearly two males.  Were those translations of that verse affected by modern politics?

Comment: @RayButterworth - again, the words "women' and "men" do not occur anywhere in the text.  I have added a final paragraph about the masculine gender.